# Using the ADO.NET Entity Data Model and an ACCESS Database?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, sqlite, ado.net-entity-data-model

I'm using:

- Visual Studio 2013
- .NET Framework 4.5.1
- Microsoft Access 2010

I'm currently working on a **C#** school project that doesn't require us to use a database at all, however we can grab some extra credit if we implement a database.

I've worked with **SQLite** so far and had not much trouble setting up the connection, however we are **limited to Access** for the project.

I would like to use the database in an **ADO.NET Entity Data Model**, but upon trying to add the **.edmx** Item via the solution explorer it doesn't let me choose "Access Database".

Is there any way to get an **Access Database and the EDM** to work together?

Comment: Download Access ADO.NET Provider then install it the option will be availible

Answer (score 1):

There is a [JetEntityFrameworkProvider](https://github.com/bubibubi/JetEntityFrameworkProvider) available on github. Compile the code and run the `Install.cmd` from `JetDdexProvider` folder:

[image]

To get DDEX Provider installed.